# From Ng video: Using feature normalization with polynomial regression

Tags: statistics, reference-request, optimization, regression, machine-learning

In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MnEa_xHm1j8) on machine learning by Andrew Ng, called "Features and Polynomial Regression", at time 4:34, he mentions the possibility of feature normalization in polynomial regression. By which he means, I believe, applying an affine transformation to the feature vector $(1, x, x^2, \dotsc, x^{n-1})$ so that the variances of the $x^i$ are closer to one another.

Does anyone know of a reference on this practice? I'd like to investigate it and its effects. (That is, the specific application of feature normalization to polynomial regression. Not just feature normalization in general.)

Comment: Probably something like normalization concept in statistics : removing mean values and dividing by standard deviation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization_(statistics) maybe Student's T statistic or feature scaling.

Comment: @mathreadler I understand feature normalization. I'm interested in the consequences of applying it in this specific way.

Comment: Aah, okay. Yes it sounds like good idea to learn. Also regularization of the coefficients of polynomials (or other kernels) is very useful to learn if you have not done so much of it yet. It can help to avoid overfitting and give simpler models.